# Equal sign, regarding to tensorflow dataset, does not really assign values to variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, shuffle, tensorflow-datasets

I found something interesting when using operations of tensorflow dataset. Let me show you code first:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset1=dataset.shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=False) 
dataset2=dataset.shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

ds11=dataset1.take(7)
ds12=dataset1.skip(7)
ds21=dataset2.take(7)
ds22=dataset2.skip(7)
ds22s=ds22.shuffle(7)
print(list(dataset2.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds11.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds12.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds21.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds22.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds22s.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

***Output:***

[3, 0, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 1, 6, 2]

[2, 0, 4, 8, 5, 3, 6]

[1, 9, 7]

[2, 6, 8, 0, 7, 3, 9]

[2, 8, 5]

[1, 0, 2]

So, the problem is that the last two printed results should have the same elements(of course not same order); but, as you can see, the fact was not that.

My guess is that **ds22** is not really assigned, but rather, we defined an operation of how to obtain it, so when we are using it, the data we needed can be generated automatically by the defined operations.

Or, can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset1=dataset.shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=False) 
dataset2=dataset.shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

ds11=dataset1.take(7)
ds12=dataset1.skip(7)
ds21=dataset2.take(7)

ds22=dataset2.skip(7)
ds22s=ds22 #.shuffle(7)
print(list(dataset2.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds11.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds12.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds21.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds22.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(list(ds22s.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

The results are same.
The reasoning behind is that when you write `ds22=dataset2.skip(7)` you mean to take first 7 samples, discard them and then take one more and display it.
So, when you write `print(list(ds22.as_numpy_iterator()))` This reads all remaining data from that dataset and returns it as a list.
Now, if you do the assignment, it means you have the exact same object in `ds22s` as in `ds22`. So, by writing `print(list(ds22s.as_numpy_iterator()))` you re-iterate on the whole dataset once more, with different shuffling applied this time. If you disable `reshuffle_each_iteration` the results will be identical, because on the second iteration over the dataset, the shuffling alignment was exactly the same.
I hope this answers your question. Feel free to ask for details.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! So  ```ds22``` is actually an object, instead of some real values like numpy matrix, right? Then, your answer does make great sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Trunway happy to help :) it is, the `ds22s` is a reference to the same object as `ds22`. If you know a bit of python, at the end of each function like `shuffle`, `skip` and so on you return the pointer to `self`. So, yes, It is actually an object.